# Creating Parameter's for Api request in Alamofire.

Tags: ios, mongodb, swift2, alamofire

I am using Xcode and swift 2 for creating a chat app for iOS platform. We are using asp.net mvc for creating the Api and mongodb as our database. Our SignUp model Contains Fields for Email and Password. 
My Model is

```
public class SignUpViewModel
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And the Api method is

```
public JsonResult Sign_Up(SignUpViewModel signupviewmodel)
    {
    }
```

How can i pass and  retrieve parameter's (data) as Model using Alamofire?

Comment: what is your exact response which server is expecting

Comment: @Johnny A model data with email and password as parameter's.

Comment: Like   using javascript we do something like this for passing model data  to the controller. say i have a tax model(in asp.net mvc)   `var taxModel = {
        TaxName: $('#txtTaxName').val(),
        TaxPercent: $('#txtRate').val(),
    }
  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'taxModel': taxModel }),

        url: '/User/TaxMastersubmit',
        success: function (data) {
            window.location.href = data;

        },
     
    }); `

Comment: You should start by reading through our [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire).